# Calling sql server stored procedure from VB 2008 with two outbound parameters

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Stored procedure is to return a recordset and two results.
When executed from SQL server management studio it returns the recordset and a value for `@NumItems` and value for `@Reason`. However when called from VB I get the `@Reason` but 0 for `@NumItems` when it should return `@@rowcount` which is 4.
`@Reason` is coming back with value of "OK" but `@NumItems` is coming back as 0.

End of `SProc` has

```
set @NumItems = @@ROWCOUNT
set @Reason = 'OK' -- process completed successfully
at end. The recordset when executed has four rows and @NumItems has returnvalue of 4 in SQL SERVER
```

Any ideas?

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim strConnection As String = ""
    strConnection = strConnectionInfo
    Dim sqlCommand As New SqlCommand
    Dim sqlConnection As New SqlConnection
    sqlConnection.ConnectionString = strConnection
    sqlConnection.Open()
    Try
        With sqlCommand
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .CommandText = "dbo.spRestockMinMax"
            .Parameters.Add("@NumItems", SqlDbType.BigInt).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            .Parameters.Add("@Reason", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            .Connection = sqlConnection
        End With
        sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
        'Dim NumItems As Long = sqlCommand.Parameters("@NumItems").Value.ToString
        da.SelectCommand = sqlCommand
        da.Fill(dt)
        dv = New DataView(dt)
        Me.dgMinMaxReplenish.DataSource = dv
        Dim myReason As String = sqlCommand.Parameters("@Reason").Value.ToString
        Dim NumItems As Long = sqlCommand.Parameters("@NumItems").Value.ToString
        If UCase(myReason) = "OK" Then
            If NumItems > 0 Then
                MsgBox("Replenishment List Created with " & NumItems & " added for replenishment", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Replenishment List Created")
            Else
                MsgBox("No Items found needing replenishment", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "No Items Needed")
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Something happenned during stored procedure", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        txtSystemMessages.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
    If dgMinMaxReplenish.RowCount > 1 Then
        dgMinMaxReplenish.Visible = True
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you stored procedure does internally, but you are running it two times. The first time in the ExecuteScalar call, the second time in the Fill call and you read the output parameters after the second call. Probably the procedure produces a different output when called in this sequence and without any changes to the underlying data.

So, perhaps you could simply remove the call to ExecuteScalar and run directly the Fill call